# Getting error while installing express-generator on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am getting error while installing express-generator

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/2.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sorted-object/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/2.7.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sorted-object/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-readlink
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-readlink
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
/usr/local/bin/express -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

I think this is why I can not use express command on terminal.

it is giving me below error while running command

```
$ express -h 
bash: /usr/bin/express: No such file or directory
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

can anyone shade light on this? why i am getting 304?

Comment: do you have express installed globally ? not just the express-generator

Answer (score 0):

You need to install express. Try:

```
npm install -g express
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/bin/express -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express


bash: /usr/bin/express: No such file or directory
```

These two lines are not matching obviously. So, as a quick solution, you can try to link them manually by [ln](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/ln.1.html):

`[sudo] ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express /usr/bin/express`

---

The other question, "can anyone shade light on this? why i am getting 304?"

304 means "resource has not been modified since last requested", so nothing to worry about it. Since you installed it before and it hasn't change until your next install, you're getting this http status code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge, i have linked express, now it is saying.
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: That's strange. Could you please type `which node` and paste the output here. It'll basically show where is your `node` binary.

Answer (score 0):

**304 status code:**

If the client has done a conditional GET and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified since the date and time specified in If-Modified-Since field, the server responds with a 304 status code and does not send the document body to the client.

So as you can see, **it is not an error.**

You can find more details about status codes at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

**Note:** Not only this module, but almost all modules will show 304 status code when installing.